# Google Chrome middle click scroll inconsistent acceleration

Tags: google-chrome

Clicking mouse scroll(middle mouse button) activates mouse-move-scrolling in Google Chrome. Since yesterday I noticed the behaviour of it was changed.

Previously scrolling speed was linearly increasing(or decreasing) with mouse vertical movement. Now scrolling speed doubles or tripples with even slightest mouse movements. Web pages now scroll in "jumps" of scrolling speed, which is annoying.

Is this a bug or a feature and how do I enable the old behaviour?

Windows 10 64-bit, Chrome 85.0.4183.83

Comment: After a week of not using my comptuer, since yesterday I'm now getting this too on Chrome 85.0.4183.83. Did you ever manage to fix this? EDIT: I see that there is a bug report for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1122950&q=middle%20scroll&can=2